# CSS Icons are working locally in the app, but are not showing on Heroku?

Tags: php, css, cakephp, heroku, web-deployment

So I have this app, just deployed on Heroku: http://jobsboardd.herokuapp.com/

And as you can see, instead of some fancy icons there are some strange symbols(rectangle)? I know it's a common thing with ruby apps, and I couldn't find anything related to php.

And according to the html code, every css file is loaded as it should. So what can be causing it and how i can fix it?

Comment: I don't see icons or strange symbols. Not sure what to look at.

Comment: What is supposed to appear? What code did you use to generate this part of the page?

Comment: What do you mean? Near every navbar button there is a symbol like this □ instead ofnormal icons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've check in the site's code, you are using [HTML Kickstart](http://www.99lime.com/elements/) Toolkit. The Icons that you are looking for belongs to another plugin called [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/). See if all the files in the css and fonts are accessible and mapped correctly. I've noticed when I check in the browser's developer console that this [image](http://jobsboardd.herokuapp.com/css/css/img/gray_jean.png) is missing so its possible others are not accessible as well.